# Sort by date modified while in icon view in Finder

Tags: macos, finder

When I group by `Date Modified`, then it creates certain groups such as `Previous 30 days`, `April`, `March`, ...

But the files in these groups are not sorted by `Date Modified`.

To view these files also sorted by `Date Modified`, I need to switch to the list view.

Is there a way to achieve the same while staying in Icon View?

Answer (score 0):

I had `Sort By` in `Show View Options` set to `Kind`, changed it to `Date Modified` and it works as expected.